# How to solve TypeError: spyOn andReturn is not a function?

Tags: javascript, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am trying to run my jasmine unit test for a service. I have mocked out the $location but getting an error:

```
app.factory('testService', function($location) {
  return {
    config: function() {
      var host = $location.absUrl();

      var result = '';

      if (host.indexOf('localhost') >= 0) {
        return 'localhost'
      }

      if (host.indexOf('myserver') >= 0) {
        return 'myserver'
      }

    }

  };
});
```

My test looks like this:

```
describe('testing service', function () {
    var configService, $rootScope, $location;

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));
    beforeEach(inject(function (_$location_) {
        //$rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $location = _$location_;
        //configService=_configService_;
        spyOn($location, 'absUrl').andReturn('localhost');
    }));

    it('should return something  ', function () {
        inject(function (configService) {
            //expect($location.absUrl).toHaveBeenCalled();
            //expect($rootScope.absUrl()).toBe('localhost');

            var result= configService.config($location);
            expect(result).toBe('localhost');
        });
    });
});
```

This is the error I am getting:
 TypeError: spyOn(...).andReturn is not a function?

Answer (score 23):

Jasmine 2.0 changed some of the spy syntax. See the [Jasmine 2.0 docs](https://web.archive.org/web/20150913045902/https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies:_%3Ccode%3Eand.returnValue%3C/code%3E).

Please use:

```
spyOn($location, 'absUrl').and.returnValue('localhost');
```